# in Spring, what is the best way to dynamically create different objects of a certain class, each object being able to access a Spring bean?

Tags: spring, javabeans

Say I have a file with each line depicting a different command (but of the same kind), which I want to read out and check and run and maybe do other operations such as merging, comparing and most importantly, store the commands into database.

To do that, I create the `Command` Class, and `new` a new Command object while reading each line of the file. Now the problem is, a Command object need to make use of, say a Spring bean which provides database access. As a result, I have to pass in that bean as a constructor argument of the Command class, which is very ugly, which doesn't seem to be the "Spring way"... 
and I don't want to use `ApplicationContextAware` to make my class coupled to the Spring context.

Is there a best practice for this situation?

*I very new to Spring and I know it might be a dumb question ...*

Comment: I don't agree passing bean as a constructor argument is ugly. Honestly I would prefer this to aspects or other heavy machinery for such simple purpose.

Comment: I now agree with you and prefer the constructor way. I also checked Spring's _lookup method injection_, which is mentioned in the Spring reference with a very similar example. But I still don't think that's a neat solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `CommandFactory` that is coupled with spring and use that in your consumer instead. If the factory implements an interface you are not coupling yourself in the consumer and you don't close your possibilities of using a different -non spring coupled- one at a later point (e.g. testing).

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think it is the best way to make the classes created by `new` Spring Beans.

Therefor annotate them with `@Configurable`, enable AspectJ, and read the Spring Reference [Chapter 7.8.1 Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable)

Comment: I don't want to use AspectJ. It's too much an overkill for such a simple situation.